# How to remove durable subscription using stompit

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, stomp

We are using ActiveMQ 5.16.1 with the [stompit](https://github.com/gdaws/stompit) client to create a durable subscription in our NodeJS app using the following code snippet:

```
  var connectOptions = {
    "host": "",
    "port": amqPort,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    checkServerIdentity: () => { },
    "connectHeaders": {
        "heart-beat": "15000,15000",// hear-beat of 15 seconds
        'login': 'admin',
         'passcode': 'admin',
         'client-id' : "agent-manager"
    }
  };

  var server1 =  connectOptions;
  server1.host = amqPrimaryHost;
  var server2 = connectOptions;
  server2.host = amqSecondaryHost;
   
   var amqSubscription;
     var subscribeHeaders = {
            "destination": "/topic/delivery-reports",          
            "activemq.subscriptionName": "channel_manager_delivery_reports",
            "ack": "client-individual"                          
    };
    var connectionManager = new stompit.ConnectFailover([server1,server2], reconnectOptions);
       connectionManager.connect(function (error, client, reconnect){
        if (error) {
            logger.error("Terminal error, gave up reconnecting ", error);
            return;
        }
        client.on("error", function (error) {
            if(!client)
              reconnect();
        });
    
   
        amqSubscription=client.subscribe(subscribeHeaders, function (error, message,subscription) {
            logger.info("going to subscribe")
            if (error) {
                logger.error("Subscription failed. Going to disconnect", error);
                subscription.unsubscribe();
               // reconnect();
            
            }
            logger.info("subscribed")  
        });
    
    });

   function unsubscribe () {
        
        logger.info("Going to unsub")
        amqSubscription.unsubscribe({"activemq.subscriptionName":"channel_manager_delivery_reports"})

   };
```

However, when I call the `unsubscribe`, it only changes the `Subscriber` active status to false but does not remove it from the active subscribers' list as shown in the screenshot.[image]

Getting the following exception in stomp.logs.

```
2021-05-12 05:20:14,826 [0.1:50251@61613] WARN  ProtocolConverter              - Exception occurred for client agent-manager (tcp://127.0.0.1:50251) processing: UNSUBSCRIBE -> javax.jms.JMSException: Durable consumer is in use
2021-05-12 05:20:14,826 [0.1:50251@61613] DEBUG ProtocolConverter              - Exception detail
javax.jms.JMSException: Durable consumer is in use
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.TopicRegion.removeSubscription(TopicRegion.java:220)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.removeSubscription(RegionBroker.java:457)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.removeSubscription(BrokerFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.removeSubscription(AdvisoryBroker.java:396)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.removeSubscription(BrokerFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.removeSubscription(BrokerFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.removeSubscription(BrokerFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processRemoveSubscription(TransportConnection.java:419)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.RemoveSubscriptionInfo.visit(RemoveSubscriptionInfo.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:331)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:45)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:301)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompTransportFilter.sendToActiveMQ(StompTransportFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.sendToActiveMQ(ProtocolConverter.java:179)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompUnsubscribe(ProtocolConverter.java:714)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompCommand(ProtocolConverter.java:251)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompTransportFilter.onCommand(StompTransportFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-05-12 05:20:14,827 [0.1:50251@61613] TRACE ProtocolConverter              - Command that caused the error: UNSUBSCRIBE
activemq.subscriptionName:channel_manager_delivery_reports
receipt:1
id:1
```

Any suggestion on how to remove the durable subscription properly via stompit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to disconnect the connection which the durable subscriber is using. This deactivates the subscription and will prevent the `JMSException: Durable consumer is in use` you're seeing.

Then you need to *reconnect* using the same `client-id` header value which you used on your `CONNECT` frame for the connection used to subscribe.

Then need to pass the `activemq.subscriptionName` header in the `UNSUBSCRIBE` frame just like you did for the `SUBSCRIBE` frame, e.g.:

```
amqSubscription.unsubscribe({"activemq.subscriptionName": "channel_manager_delivery_reports"})
```

To be clear, this was resolved awhile back via [AMQ-1890](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-1890). You can see the [corresponding source code](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/activemq-5.16.1/activemq-stomp/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/stomp/ProtocolConverter.java#L703) which checks for the header and removes the subscription. You can also see the [unit test](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/e432a78c19e9c30b5afd84e591a428734ad55431/activemq-stomp/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/stomp/StompTest.java#L1461) which subscribes, disconnects, reconnects, and unsubscribes the durable subscription.

If you still have trouble then it may be worth turning on STOMP trace logging in the broker using [these instructions](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp#debugging) to ensure the `UNSUBSCRIBE` frame is being received with the expected `activemq.subscriptionName` header.

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: code updated. I also tried with the  same` subscribeHeaders` headers in UNSUBSCRIBE frame but still no luck

Comment: I am using 5.16.1 version

Comment: When unsubscribing ensure that you connect with the client-id used to create the subscription.

Comment: getting  `javax.jms.JMSException: Durable consumer is in use` exception in stomp.logs

Comment: confirmed from logs  `activemq.subscriptionName` is beign received as expected.

Comment: I always get `Durable consumer is in use` exception in stomp logs after setting the frame   `{"activemq.subscriptionName": "channel_manager_delivery_reports"}`  in unsubscribe call.
`

Comment: I updated my answer to deal with the `JMSException: Durable consumer is in use` issue. Hope that helps!